# MySQL: Cannot update JSON column to convert value from float to integer

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL table with a JSON column. I want to update some rows in the JSON column to change a json value from a float to an integer. e.g `{"a": 20.0}` should become `{"a": 20}`. It looks like MySQL finds these 2 values equivalent, so it never bothers to update the row.

Here is the state of my `test` table:

```
mysql> describe test;
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| val   | json | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------------+
| id | val         |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | {"a": 20.0} |
+----+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My aim is to change `val` to `{"a": 20}`

I've tried the following queries:

```
mysql> update test set val=JSON_OBJECT("a", 20) where id=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

(0 rows changed)

```
mysql> update test
    set val=JSON_SET(
        val,
        "$.a",
        FLOOR(
            JSON_EXTRACT(val, "$.a")
        )
    )
where id=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

(0 rows changed)

```
mysql> insert into test (id, val) values (1, JSON_OBJECT("a", 20)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), val=VALUES(val);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

(0 rows affected)

It looks like it doesn't matter how I try to write it, whether I attempt to modify the existing value, or specify a whole new JSON_OBJECT. So I'm wondering if the reason is simply that MySQL considers the before & after values to be equivalent.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: No problem with your first update [statement](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e0e2e9af217704fcb1726f08e42a647) .

Comment: Interesting, seems to work there but not in my local MySQL server. Maybe something related to the engine and/or configuration? I'm running MySQL8.0.22 on Mac OSX
```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the value to something completely different first?

Comment: Yes. That's the workaround I ended up going with. I first changed the value to `{"a": 20, "whatever": 1}` and then changed it back to `{"a": 20}`... It really seems like `{"a": 20}` appears equivalent to `{"a": 20.0}` to MySQL, so it doesn't bother to update the value at all.

Comment: Please do `SHOW  WARNINGS;` immediately after the `INSERT` -- The 2 warnings might be useful to this discussion.

Comment: @RickJames I only get warnings when I try `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The warnings are: `'VALUES function' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use an alias (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) AS alias) and replace VALUES(col) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause with alias.col instead`

The other methods I've tried (e.g: UPDATE SET val=... WHERE id=1) have no warnings.

Comment: @tomas - Please show the entire statement with the 'deprecated' problem.

Comment: @RickJames it's the last statement in the question:

insert into test (id, val) values (1, JSON_OBJECT("a", 20)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), val=VALUES(val);

Comment: I found the deprecation...  See my "Answer".

Answer (score 0):

(This does not address the original Question, but addresses a problem encountered in Answering it.)

Gross...  8.0 has a naughty history of all-too-quickly removing something after recently deprecating it.  Beware.  Here is the issue with `VALUES` from the Changelog for 8.0.20:

----- 2020-04-27 8.0.20 General Availability -- -- -----

The use of [VALUES()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) to access new row values in [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statements is now deprecated, and is subject to removal in a future MySQL release. Instead, you should use aliases for the new row and its columns as implemented in MySQL 8.0.19 and later.

For example, the statement shown here uses [VALUES()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) to access new row values:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

Henceforth, you should instead use a statement similar to the following, which uses an alias for the new row:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS new
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = new.a+new.b;
```

Alternatively, you can employ aliases for both the new row and each of its columns, as shown here:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS new(m,n,p)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = m+n;
```

For more information and examples, see [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: alas, the issue is not only with the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. 

I understand the warning there, but I would have expected this to work: `update test set val=JSON_OBJECT("a", 20) where id=1;` WIth that not working, the only option left was to first set the value to something completely different and then change it to my intended value.

Comment: You  can try truncate

Comment: Select truncate(value, no. Of decimal places)       e. G.,   select truncate(1.9999, 0)  is 1